# Appcelerator Android simulator ends with "code 1"?

Tags: android, sdk, aptana, appcelerator

On My mac I'm trying to build an App using Appcelerator. Using the Android SDK Manager I installed the Android SDK. The iPhone simulator works (although it is really small), but unfortunately, trying to run the Android Simulator ends in the following:

```
[ERROR] :  Emulator process exited with code 1
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 990ms
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

The Android SDK stuff I installed is displayed below. Does anybody know what I need to do to get the Android Simulator to work?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have also had issues with the titanium Android emulators. I am using a mac VM on windows.
For me, the solution was to use a different display resolution.

Try the following config:
Google APIs Android 4.3.
HVGA
See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing) for an explanation of the different sizes.

Also, when the IOS Simulator is open. Go to Window -> scale and ensure it is set to 100%.
Or under Device try a different iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately we've moved away from Appcelerator in favor of native development. A pity I must say, but thanks anyway for the answer!